# Strange code additions by VScode or its plugins

Tags: babeljs, eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

I've been experiencing some undesirable behaviour in my VScode for some time now. The editor or one of its extensions will add some lines like below automatically to the top of the file:-

```
const { parse } = require("dotenv/types");
const { fail } = require("tap");
```

My code does not need these at this stage and they prevent my code from compiling causing a silent failure. Is there some setting i can add/change to prevent these auto additions.

I have following extensions enabled in the workspace:-

- Babel Javascript
- DotENV
- EsLint
- Prettier - Code Formatter
- html to jsx
- Azure Account
- Azure Databases
- Todo Tree

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks Ahead.